# On subgroups of abelian groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

Let $G$ be a product of $n$ finite cyclic groups. Is every subgroup of $G$ also a product of (at most) $n$ finite cyclic groups ?

I do not know the answer to this question, but I'm tempted to say yes. I'm aware of the classification theorem of abelian groups but I don't know how to use it here, I've also tried modules and dual groups but nothing serious came out of it.

Comment: Any finitely generated abelian group is a product of cyclic groups, and any subgroup of an abelian group is abelian. Is your issue the "at most $n$" part?

Comment: Yes of course !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The finite Abelian group $G$ is a direct product of at most $t$ cyclic groups if and only if each of its Sylow $p$-subgroups is a direct product of at most $t$ cyclic groups. Hence it is enough to consider the case that $G$ is a $p$-group, so suppose it is. Now if $G$ is the direct product of exactly $t$ cyclic subgroups, then $G_{p} = \{g \in G: g^{p} = 1_{G} \}$ is a subgroup of order exactly $p^{t}.$ Hence $H_{p} = \{ h \in H : h^{p} = 1_{G} \}$ has order at most $p^{t},$ so that $H$ is a direct product of at most $t$ cyclic groups.

Answer (score 2):

There is a free abelian group of rank $n$ and an epimorphism $\pi: F \to G$. Given a subgroup $H \leq G$, its preimage under $\pi$ is a subgroup of $F$, hence is free abelian of rank $\leq n$ and so is generated by at most $n$ elements; furthermore, a basis for $\pi^{-1}(H)$ may be chosen so that the basis elements of $\ker\pi$ are multiples of the basis elements for $\pi^{-1}(H)$, so that the image $H$ is a direct product of at most $n$ cyclic groups.

Comment: This is nice ! Why generated implied by $n$ elements imply product of cyclic groups ? I can think of an argument using modules: chose an adapted base for the kernel of a surjective module morphism $\mathbb{Z}^{m}\rightarrow H$, but perhaps you have something more elementary.